# Convert recordset to array

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

I am  quite new to access and sql. Trying to convert the data in my recordset into an array (Excel VBA) so that I could work with the data without pasting the data on a spreadsheet.

Did some research and most sites mentioned that GetRows function would work but I got an run-time error '3021'. Any advice on how to fix this, please? Thanks!

```
Dim conConnect As Object
Dim cmdCommand As Object
Dim rstRecordSet As Object
Dim DBPath, StrCon As String
Dim tblarray As Variant

Set conConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmdCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set rstRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
DBPath = "C:\Users\Documents\DbMhours.accdb"

    conConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & _
    ";Mode=Read|Write"

    conConnect.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    conConnect.Open

    With cmdCommand
        .ActiveConnection = conConnect
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblOverallStats;"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    With rstRecordSet
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmdCommand
    End With

    'Call StatsSum function in module
    tblarray = StatsSum (rstRecordSet)

    rstRecordSet.Close

    conConnect.Close


Function StatsSum(Summary As Object) As Variant 'Input to be recordset from workbook

    tblarray = Summary.GetRows

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is wrong - it should be:

```
Function StatsSum(Summary As Object) As Variant 'Input to be recordset from workbook

    StatsSum = Summary.GetRows

End Function
```

You should also check to see if you have any records first using `.EOF`

Comment: Thanks! Added in the .EOF and MoveFirst to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue myself, I realized that the simplest way may simply be brute force:

```
With rstRecordset
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    For i = 1 To .RecordCount
        for j = 1 to .Fields.Count
             tblArray(i,j) = .Fields(j).Value
        Next j
        .MoveNext
    Next i
End With
```